# How to model 24 hours demand into a daily shift schedule?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, pyomo, minizinc

I am working on a weekly staff scheduling optimization problem with 24/7 demand.

The binary decision variable is: X(staff, day, shift).

There are several shift sets for everyday like 8-17 for full time. 14-19 for part time, and 20-6 for night shift.

The 0-1 shift/hour matrix is: Shift_Hour_Map(shift, hour) which has 24 hour as columns, shifts as rows.

The demand is formulated as:  Demand(day, hour).

The current constraints are:

1. weekly up/lower limit total hours for every staff.

   2.The demand coverage constraint is :
   [image]
   The constraint like no assignment of daily shift after a night shift is not necessary, because the night shift is basically sleeping on site and staff sometimes is willing to pick a morning shift right after the overnight shift.

This would be fine if there's no **overnight shift**. 
How do I model the constraint to consider the overnight shift? 
And also, how to model the next Monday's early morning demand (last shift of Sunday)?

Do I just model as 24*7 hours and remove the day index? 
I can use MiniZinc or Pyomo.

Comment: For how long is a person scheduled? It's perhaps better to use the actual scheme, e.g. weekly or by 2 weeks, instead of trying to tweak everything into a single day scheme.  It might help if you state a little more details about this and also show what you have done so far.

Comment: The shifts are preconfigured like full time shift 8-17, part time 8-12. Staff can pick a set of available shifts during the day. I am not sure how to model the overnight shift to the constraint.

Comment: Hmm, there must be at least one type of shift more, the overnight shift, or isn't it? For how long is this kind of scheme (i.e. how long until it start over again)? If the staff can pick any shift, exactly what are the constraints that you are trying to satisfy? Such as: "during days there must be at least (or exactly) n person working", "during night m person working", "after a night shift a person must be free 2 days", etc etc.

Comment: Yes, the night shift is like 20-6. The constraints right now are weekly total up/limit for each staff. The staff actually are willing to do a morning shift right after a night shift in my case(night shift is basically sleeping on site). The demand is a forecast of service and breakdown to number of labor required for every hour.

Comment: Would you please update your question with this info and as much details as possible for us to better understand exactly what you are looking for,